# Flash of unstyled content in Gatsby when using global style sheet

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styling

I am working on a gatsby project where everything is working fine, except for when I load any page of the website as there is a flash of unstyled content for like a second. The issue persists in all the pages and my research on fixing this issue revealed this to be a persisting issue when working with styled-components. My project does not use styled components as there is one global style sheet that is shared across the project as the style sheet is loaded in the gatsby-browser.js.

code in the config below. Can anyone assist me here?

```
    require('dotenv').config({
    path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
});

module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: 'name of site',
        siteUrl: `https://lffff.com`,
        description: `some description.`,
        author: 'name',
        image: 'image link'
    },
    pathPrefix: '/v2',
    plugins: [
        'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
        'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
        `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `images`,
                path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
            options: {
                spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
                accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
            options: {
                rule: {
                    include: /assets/
                }
            }
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
            options: {
                name: `GatsbyJS`,
                short_name: `GatsbyJS`,
                start_url: `/`,
                display: `standalone`,
                icon: 'src/images/5f8e0f3ace9452d1a7fbe65b_LP_Logo_Square.png'
            }
        }
    ]
```

};

this is what is in gatsby-browser.js

```
import './src/styles/globalStyles.css';
```

Comment: Is the system waiting for everything to be loaded?

Comment: Can you share the `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js` files?

Comment: @AHaworth how would I find out if it is doing this?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I added whats in gatsby-browser.js to the question. I dont have a gatsby-ssr.js file here

Comment: Are you building and serving your site using path prefix?

Comment: @FerranBuireu nope

Answer (score 0):

You are using [prefixed paths](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/) at:

```
pathPrefix: '/v2',
```

In development (`gatsby develop`) paths don't need to be prefixed, however, during the build and server process (`gatsby build && gatsby server`) it's a needed specification

If you are building a path manually, you can use [`withPrefix`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/#add-the-path-prefix-to-paths-using-withprefix) helper function that prepends your path prefix in production.

Change your build and serve commands to:

```
gatsby build --prefix-paths
```

And:

```
gatsby serve --prefix-paths
```

If you are not using the `pathPrefix`, just remove it from your configuration and keep your commands as at the beginning.